# History of $\frac d{dt}\tan^{-1}(t)=\frac 1{1+t^2}$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ho.history-overview, teaching

Let $\theta = \tan^{-1}(t)$. Nowadays it is taught:

1º that
$$
\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac 1{dt\,/\,d\theta} = \frac 1{1+t^2},
\tag1
$$

2º that, via the fundamental theorem of calculus, this is equivalent to
$$
\theta = \int_0^t\frac{du}{1+u^2},
\tag2
$$

3º that, expanding the integrand in a geometric series and integrating term by term, this becomes the <del>Nilakantha</del> Madhava-Gregory-Leibniz formula
$$
\theta = t - \frac{t^3}3+\frac{t^5}5-\frac{t^7}7+\dots.
\tag3
$$

> **Question:** Who first proved $(1)$ in print as we do, by deriving an inverse function?

---

> **I can’t find it in Nilakantha:**

According to [Ranjan Roy (1990, p.300)](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1081274), Nilakantha first published $(3)$ without proof in his [*Tantrasangraha* (1501)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantrasamgraha); a later commentary known as [*Yuktibhasa*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuktibhasa) contains a proof by rectification of an arc of circle, which is beautiful but certainly not quite the same as $(1)$.

> **I can’t find it in Gregory:**

According to [Dehn & Hellinger (1943, p.149)](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=7715), Gregory communicated $(3)$ in a [1671 letter to Collins](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k99557b/f96), and never published a proof; speculation exists that he found it by deriving $\tan^{-1}$ enough times to figure out its Taylor series at $0$, but in any event, he left no trace of how he may have computed these derivatives.

> **I can’t find it in Leibniz:**

According to [González-Velasco (2011, p.347)](//books.google.com/books?id=0sTd4qJgOmsC&pg=PA347), Leibniz communicated $(3)$ in 1674 letters to Oldenburg and Huygens, and later published the case $t=1$ in [*Acta Eruditorum* (1682, pp.41-46)](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/12799491); his unpublished proof is available (many times over) in the 700+ pages of his Collected Works, [Vol. VII,6](//leibnizedition.de/reihen/reihe-vii/). There, or in the nice exposition given in [Hairer & Wanner (1996, 2nd printing, pp.49-50)](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1410751), one sees that he was squaring the circle in an elaborate way which has nothing to do with $(1)$.

Of course Leibniz must have become aware of $(1)$ and $(2)$ *at some point*, as (later!) inventor of the notation that makes them almost automatic. Unfortunately, I can’t find any written evidence of that. Maybe someone else will have better luck!

(The closest I can find is a [1707 letter of Wolff to Leibniz](//archive.org/details/briefwechselzwis00leibiala/page/72), where the new notation is used to write in effect that $d\theta = dt:(1+t^2)$, and then deduce $(2)$ and $(3)$. The two correspondents may well have had in mind the modern proof $(1)$ of this differential relation, but neither says so.)

> **I can’t find it in Jacob Bernoulli:**

With Leibniz notation spreading, one might think that a disciple would write $(1)$ at the first opportunity. But that’s not what Jacob B. does to rectify a unit circle in [*Positionum de Seriebus Infinitis Pars Tertia* (Basel, 1696, Prop. XLV)](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/1040687): instead, he parametrizes one with $(x,y)=$ $\bigl(x,\sqrt{2x-x^2}\bigr)$ and then expresses the resulting arc length differential — also seen in Leibniz ([1686](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/12799541)) — as
$$
d\theta
=\sqrt{\smash{dx^2+dy^2}\vphantom{a^2}}
=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}
=\frac{2d\mathsf t}{1+\mathsf t^2}
\tag{$*$}
$$
$(=\mathrm{LH}$ on his [Fig. 3](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/1041081)$)$ by introducing a “diophantine” (a.k.a. [Weierstraß](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#Euler_and_Weierstrass)) substitution $\smash{\mathsf t=\frac xy}$ $=\smash{\tan\frac\theta2}$ $(=\mathrm{BI}$ on the figure, as he notes; so his $\mathsf t=\tan\mathrm{BAI}$ is not our $t=\tan\mathrm{BAH})$. While this still proves $(2)$ and $(3)$ for the halved angle and its tangent, the argument definitely isn’t $(1)$.

$\hspace{8.5em}$[image]

> **I can’t find it in Johann Bernoulli:**

When faced with the task of integrating $\smash{\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}$ in his [paper on rational integrals (1702)](//archive.org/details/histoiredelacad02laca/page/296), Johann B. proposes two substitutions:

- The first (in Probl. I, Corol.) comes from the partial fraction decomposition $\frac1{1+t^2}=\frac{1/2}{1+it} + \frac{1/2}{1-it}$, and consists in putting $u = \frac{1+it}{1-it}$ so that
  $
  \frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\frac{du}{2iu}=d\left[\frac1{2i}\log\frac{1+it}{1-it}\right]
  $.
- The second (in Probl. II) consists in putting $u=\frac1{1+t^2}$ so that $\frac{dt}{1+t^2} = \frac{-du}{\sqrt{4(u-u^2)}}$, which he knows (perhaps by recognizing half $(*)$ with $x=2(1-u)$?) is a “circular sector or arc differential”.

Neither of these is the substitution $\theta = \tan^{-1}(t)$, which *via* $(1)$ would have led directly to $\frac{dt}{1+t^2} = d\theta$. And in later papers ([1712](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/1052075), [1719](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/1052564)) Bernoulli is content to describe this relation as “well-known”.

> **I can’t find it in de Moivre:**

[Schneider (1968, footnotes 248 & 250)](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1554118) seems to claim that a 1708 letter of de Moivre to Bernoulli has the proof $(1)$ and also the “Euler” formula $\theta=\smash{\frac1i}\log(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$. But this is not borne out by the letter’s text in ([1931](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0006.33801), pp.241-257): there, as also in his paper ([1703](//doi.org/10.1098/rstl.1702.0012), p.1124) and book ([1730](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/1256174), p.44), de Moivre simply states $\smash{d\theta=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}$ without proving it anew.

> **I can’t find it in Euler:**

Euler was of course well aware of $(2)$, which appears for instance in his fifth paper ([1729](//archive.org/details/commentariiacade02impe/page/93), pp.93, 95) and in his later E60, 65, 66, 125, 129, 130, 162, 217, 391, 475, 482, [etc](//archive.org/details/enestrom-test). But when it comes to *proving* $(2)$ or $(3)$, then again he seems to eschew $(1)$:

- In his [precalculus book (1748, §§139-140)](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/2447308) he chooses to first establish Bernoulli’s above formula
  $$
  \theta = \frac1{2i}\log\frac{1+it}{1-it}
  \tag4
  $$
  (this he does by multiplying numerator and denominator by $\cos\theta$ so they become $e^{\pm i\theta}$), and then to deduce $(3)$ by plugging $it$ in the series for $\smash{\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$. None of this requires $(1)$, $(2)$, or any calculus.
- In his [differential calculus book (1755, §§194-197)](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/1174128) he first differentiates a similar logarithmic formula for $\theta = \sin^{-1}(s)$, namely $\theta = -i\log(\sqrt{1-s^2} + is)$, to obtain
  $$
  d\theta = \frac{ds}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}.
  \tag5
  $$
  Plugging $s = t/\sqrt{1+t^2}$ into $(5)$ then gives him $(2)$. He might as well have differentiated $(4)$ directly! Either way, $(1)$ is not used, although to be fair, Euler at least gives (§195) an alternative proof of $(5)$ using **the argument** $(1)$, but applied to $\smash{\sin^{-1}}$ instead of $\smash{\tan^{-1}}$.

> **So where can you find it?**

It’s in [Lacroix (1797, pp.113-114)](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/2481956) and its progeny. Still I have trouble believing it took over 100 years for $(1)$ to become the standard proof — hence my question.

Comment: suddenly I thought that the first place where it appeared could be… exactly this question

Comment: @PietroMajer Glad to have created some suspense! But nah, it's in just about [any textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=BzzKIwLPJB4C&pg=PA7)

Comment: Newton devised a formula for series reversion (comp inversion), same as https://oeis.org/A133437, and he tested it on the asin (see around pg. 75 of the Ferraro ref in the OEIS entry). You would think he would have done the same for tan and atan. Not exactly the same as the symbolic manipulation, but he had geometric arguments related to fluxions.

Comment: In fact, Newton seems to have dealt with basically the first three equations, according to Ferraro, as an example of more general propositions.

Comment: @TomCopeland Ferraro ([pp. 69-70](https://books.google.com/books?id=vLBJSmA9zgAC&pg=PA69)) clearly says that Newton in *De Analysi* (written c. 1669, published 1711, [Opera Omnia I, p. 264](https://archive.org/stream/NewtonIsaacOperaOmniaI/Newton%2C_Isaac_Opera_omnia_I#page/n145/mode/1up)) obtains the value (3) of the integral (2) by method 3º. I see no mention of (1), which is what the present question is about.

Comment: On the other hand, *Horsley's 1779 editorial notes* to the same Opera Omnia I, [pp. 298-299](https://archive.org/stream/NewtonIsaacOperaOmniaI/Newton%2C_Isaac_Opera_omnia_I#page/n162/mode/1up), do prove (1) by the very method attributed to Cotes in my answer below.

Comment: On pg. 69 is a ratio of derivatives (dot notation) being set equal to g(x,y). I see no reason why a nimble mind like Newton's would not see that (1) is a special case of this, and other pages show him also dealing with the series (3) and with the integral (2) as examples of his ideas. Newton with his keen interest in and use of tangent line segments, harmonic phenomena, and fluxions not investigating tan and atan, only sin and asin, seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: @TomCopeland To "see that (1) is a special case of $\frac{dy}{dx}=g(x,y)$",  you must *have* (1) to begin with. I see no evidence that Newton had it in the [section of *De Methodis*](https://archive.org/stream/methodoffluxions00newt#page/25) quoted by Ferraro. To find it somewhere was my whole question.

Comment: I have taken Ferraro's word for it that Newton arrived at $\dot{y}/\dot{x}=g(x,y)$ or an equivalent form. If you are asking about notation rather than notions, then this question is of no further interest to me.

Comment: Your equation (1) is a special case of the inverse function theorem. Pp. 76-78 of F. show that Newton was aware of this application of inversion (and much more) and derived a series for sin from asin as an example. Whether published by him or not, I find it improbable that he didn't deal with atan in a similar fashion especially since he did deal with its series expansion as F. shows on p. 70. That's my only point.

Comment: @TomCopeland Newton didn't formulate the inverse function theorem. Even if he had, you can only apply it to find $(\sin^{-1})'$ or $(\tan^{-1})'$ if you *have* $\sin'$ or $\tan'$.

Comment: Ferraro does write (twice, on pp. 64 and 78) that "the expansion of the sine was derived by using the fact that the fluxion of arcsine is an analytical expression". That must mean (5). **Is anything like (5) in Newton?** Ferraro (p. 76) quotes "[[OO, 1:285-288](https://archive.org/stream/NewtonIsaacOperaOmniaI/Newton%2C_Isaac_Opera_omnia_I#page/n155/mode/1up)]". These pages have nothing of the sort; p. 298 has (5), and p. 299 has (1), but in *1779 editorial notes by Horsley*.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler, N, if he hadn't derived the deriv of tan himself, would have learned of it from Gregory when he attempted to reproduce series derived by N.  Roy in "The discovery of the series formula for π by Leibnitz, Gregory, and Nilakantha" states in Section 3 that G derived series for the tan annd arctan in an unsuccessful attempt to reproduce a method of N that Roy says, "consisted of reversion of series, expansion by the binomial theorem, long division by series, and term by term integration." Successive derivatives of tan by Gregory are also noted.

Comment: Rather "could have learned" of it through the circle of investigators Collins, Oldenburg, Gregory, and Newton as described on pg. 20 of Isaac Newton on Mathematical Certainty and Method, Issue 4 By Niccolò Guicciardini.

Comment: @TomCopeland Roy's paper (linked in question) reproduces speculation by Turnbull ([1939](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=206)) that a) Gregory knew Taylor's formula and b) certain arrays in his private marginalia were derivative computations of $\tan$. This *might* explain the series for $\tan$, but certainly doesn't warrant Roy's **leap** (p. 300) that Gregory “must have obtained the series for $\tan^{-1}$ from $\tan'=1+\tan^2$” by... the modern method (1), (2), (3). Moreover Malet ([1993](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1252036)) strongly objects to a), b): “Turnbull...”

Comment: “somehow conveys the amazing conclusion that Gregorie was in possession of powerful analytical differential techniques similar to those developed by Leibniz and his followers. Indeed he occasionally suggested that Gregorie's results cannot be explained without post-Leibnizian differential techniques [...] Gregorie's manuscripts and correspondence, however, **contain no trace whatever of either Newtonian or Leibnizian differential techniques** [...] As we shall see, every result from the Gregorie manuscripts that Turnbull explained by means of calculus techniques may be deduced by other means.”

Comment: "somehow conveys ..." sets up a straw man, a common fallacious argument (red herring) used in MO often. Roy states that G in writing had computed what amount to successive derivatives of tan in powers of tan for a series expansion, providing a plausibility argument for Newton having the derivative of tan, if he hadn't derived it already, to counter your suggestion that he couldn't have known it. Mercator earlier had computed what we now call the Taylor series for ln(1+x) (that Newton was made aware of) without knowledge of Taylor's formalism. Newton was an expert on both derivatives and

Comment: geometry, so certainly he could have easily reproduced from infinitesimal arguments the derivative of the tan from geometric arguments such as those of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299682/geometric-intuition-for-derivatives-of-basic-trig-functions.

Comment: @TomCopeland This question is not asking for a plausibility argument that someone “[could have done](https://mathoverflow.net/q/271568)” something. It is asking where **in print** (correspondence ok, when that was normal) the derivative or fluxion of **arctangent** was first computed using the two steps of (1), viz. (in any notation)
$$
\tfrac{d\theta}{dt}=\left(\tfrac{dt}{d\theta}\right)^{-1}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\tfrac{dt}{d\theta}=1+t^2.
$$
So far it appears to be Lacroix 1797 — and for the arcsine variant, Euler 1755. If you find anything earlier, please say! Malet commits no fallacy.

Comment: Well, at least you added the Horsley ref from Ferraro after I pointed out Ferraro. My latter comments are related to the salvo of comments you made after my first three comments on the general nature of Newton's knowledge.

Comment: @TomCopeland Yes, I did. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I now believe that my question (and suggestion that proof $(1)$ should have become standard before Lacroix) relied on the **misconception** that tangent was easier to differentiate than arctangent. In fact the calculus of inverse trigonometric functions took off *earlier*, as has been explained by G. Eneström ([1905](//archive.org/details/bub_gb_vEo0AQAAMAAJ/page/n669)), C. Boyer ([1947](//www.jstor.org/stable/27953231)), or V. J. Katz ([1987](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=919063)):

> it was quite common [at first] to deal with what we call the arcsine function rather than the sine.

C. Wilson ([2001](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1805344), [2007](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3890488)) concurs and stresses that our trig *functions* with periodic graphs weren’t much seen or differentiated until Euler “found” them to solve 2nd order linear differential equations ([1741](//books.google.com/books?id=MFMVAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA235)); so much so that he still wrote in ([1749](//www.e-rara.ch/zuz/content/pageview/13571810), p.15):

> as this way of operating is not yet commonplace, it will be apropos to warn that the differentials of the formulas $\sin.$ : $\cos.$ : $\mathrm{tang}.$ : $\cot.$ are $d\,\cos.$ : $-d\,\sin.$ : $\smash[b]{\frac{d}{\cos.\,^2}}$ & $\smash[b]{-\frac{d}{\sin.\,^2}}$

— and e.g. in ([1796](//doi.org/10.1098/rstl.1796.0009), p.163) L’Huilier still computed $\tan'$ from $\arctan'$ rather than vice versa.

In this vein, $d = \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$ was not proved like $(1)$, but by a differential triangle argument similar to $(*)$ but simpler and attributed to **Cotes** (*Aestimatio errorum*, 1722): in modern notation, parametrize the unit circle with $(x,y)=\frac{(1,\,t)}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$ and obtain
$$
d\theta
=\sqrt{\smash{dx^2+dy^2}\vphantom{a^2}}
=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}
\tag6
$$
($=\mathrm{CE}$ in Cotes’ [figure](//www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/1255981), which became standard in many books even before his own — the list could almost be described as “everyone but Euler”):

`1708 Charles-René Reyneau               §590         fig. 41  
1718  John Craig                         pp.52–54              
1722  Roger Cotes (posthumous)           Lemma II              
1730  Edmund Stone                       p.63         fig. 13  
1736  James Hodgson                      p.230                 
1736  John Muller                        §247         fig. 153 
1737  Thomas Simpson                     §143                  
1742  Colin MacLaurin                    §195         fig. 52  
1743  William Emerson                    pp.171–172   fig. 76  
1748  Maria Agnesi                       p.639        fig. 4   
1749  Charles Walmesley (credits Cotes)  pp.3,53      fig. 10  
1749  William Emerson                    p.29         fig. 6   
1750  Thomas Simpson                     §142                  
1754  Louis-Antoine de Bougainville      p.24         fig. 9   
1761  Abraham Kästner                    §299         fig. 18  
1765  Jean Le Rond D’Alembert            p.640        fig. 25  
1767  Étienne Bézout                     p.146        fig. 46  
1768  Thomas Le Seur & François Jacquier p.63         fig. 7   
1774  Jean Saury                         pp.25,63     fig. 3   
1779  Samuel Horsley                     pp.298–299            
1786  Simon L’Huilier                    pp.103–104   fig. 20  
1795  Simon L’Huilier                    §76          fig. 17`

As to our usual proof $(1)$, it appears before Lacroix in 18-year-old **Legendre**’s *Theses mathematicæ* (1770), then in a book by their [common](http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Legendre.html) [teacher](http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Lacroix.html) J.-F. Marie and several others:

`1770 Adrien-Marie Legendre              pp.10,16              
1772  Joseph-François Marie              §904                  
1777  Jacques-Antoine Joseph Cousin      p.81                  
1781  Claude Bertrand                    p.140                 
1781  Louis Lefèvre-Gineau               p.31                  
1795  Simon L’Huilier                    §76                   
1797  Sylvestre-François Lacroix         pp.113–114            
1801  Joseph-Louis Lagrange              p.81                  
1810  Sylvestre-François Lacroix         pp.lii,203–204`

Comment: And, of course, Cotes worked with Newton, but died at an early age

Answer (score 25):

[*The Madhava–Gregory series*, by R. C. Gupta](http://www.slideshare.net/indianshm/gupta1973e), attributes (3) to Indian mathematician-astronomer Madhava of Sangamagrama (circa 1350–1425). He also writes that a geometric derivation which is basically equivalent to (1) can be found in the book [Yuktibhāṣā](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuktibh%C4%81%E1%B9%A3%C4%81) written by Indian astronomer Jyesthadeva (circa 1500-1601) of the Kerala school of mathematics in about 1530.

Comment: Thanks Zurab. I had followed Ranjan Roy (1990) in calling $(3)$ the Nilakantha(-Gregory-Leibniz) series, but indeed I see arguments for calling it Madhava’s instead (e.g. also in [Resonance **2** (1997), nº 11, p. 112](//doi.org/10.1007/BF02862651)). Regarding whether Madhava’s proof was “basically” $(1)$ I agree with [Pingree’s opinion](//hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7562).