# Periodic lightray paths trapped between two nested mirror circles

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

I wonder if the periodic paths of a lightray trapped between two nonconcentric circles,
each perfectly reflecting, are known.
The behavior of such rays seems chaotically complicated.  For example, left below the highlighted
initial ray has slope $\frac{1}{12}$, while that to the right has slope $\frac{1}{9}$.
(The green circle has radius $\frac{3}{4}$.) After 500 reflections, neither ray has become periodic.

   [image: Light rays trapped in annulus]

I suspect the combination of dispersive and focusing reflection 
(from the inner and outer circles respectively) 
leads to this complex behavior.
But perhaps the periodic paths are known?

I only know the 2-cycles from rays collinear with the circle centers,
and those that Noam Elkies kindly identified in his comment:
"regular $n$-gons (and $(n/k)$-gons, i.e. stars) that stay so close to the outer circle that they never hit the inner one."

(Related MO question: "[Trapped rays bouncing between two convex bodies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38307/).")

---

**Update 1**. I found one! :-)  No doubt among the "simple short cycles" that Noam had in mind:

                [image: 3-cycle]

---

**Update 2**.
With the benefit of the search terms helpfully provided by Ian Agol and Igor Riven,
I found a useful *Physical Review* paper by
G. Gouesbet, S. Meunier-Guttin-Cluzel, and G. Grehan,
"Periodic orbits in Hamiltonian chaos of the annular billiard,"
[Phys. Rev. E 65, 016212 (2001)](http://pre.aps.org/abstract/PRE/v65/i1/e016212). Their approach is more experimental than theoretical:

> Periodic orbits embedded in the phase space are 
>   systematically investigated, with a focus on inclusion-touching periodic orbits, up to symmetrical orbits of 
>   period 6. Candidates for periodic orbits are detected by investigating grayscale distance charts and, afterward, 
>   each candidate is validated (or rejected) by using analytical and/or numerical methods.

The (unstable) 3-cycle I found they label "2(1)1" in their 
(barely discernable) Fig.5 inventory below:

   [image: Fig5]

Comment: You probably want to exclude also regular $n$-gons (and $(n/k)$-gons, i.e. stars) that stay so close to the outer circle that they never hit
the inner one.  Besides those, and probably some simple short cycles besides the two 2-cycles you noted that could be described in closed form, there must be lots of cycles whose coordinates satisfy algebraic equations too complicated to solve explicitly.

Comment: It's not too hard to see that if you fix the coordinates of an initial point, then all slopes that yield periodic orbits starting from that point will form a subset of the algebraic closure in $\mathbb{R}$ of the field generated by those coordinates (and the coordinates of the centers and radii of the circles).

Comment: Those diagrams are going to get cluttered quickly: how about instead of visualising the paths as either on/off pixels, start with a uniform   color, say 255 or whatever the highest intensity is, and subtract 1 level of intensity every time you draw a line through a given point. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how to answer your question, but I'll make a reformulation of the question.

Consider the unit tangent bundle to the outer circle, and consider
the subset consisting of vectors pointing into the circle. This is 
an annulus, parameterized by $(\theta,\varphi)\in A=[0,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]/\{ (0,\varphi)\sim (2\pi,\varphi)\}$, where $\theta$ parameterizes the point on the outer circle, and $\varphi$ gives the angle that the unit vector makes with the tangent vector. One may consider the first-return map under the geodesic flow $F: A\to A$ (flow in the direction of the vector until you hit the outer circle again, then reflect). This is a piecewise smooth map. For each $\theta$, there are angles $0< f_1(\theta) < f_2(\theta) < \pi$ such that $F(\theta,\varphi)= (\theta+2\varphi, \varphi)$ for $0\leq \varphi \leq f_1(\theta)$ and $f_2(\theta)\leq \varphi \leq \pi$ (in particular, $F$ is the identity on the boundary of $A$).  For fixed $\theta$ and $f_1(\theta) < \varphi < f_2(\theta)$, $F(\theta,\varphi)$ is a more complicated trigonometric function depending on how the geodesic reflects off the inner circle and bounces back to the outer circle, but it has the property that $\varphi$ is increasing, and $\theta$ is decreasing. There is a natural measure on geodesic flow in the plane, the Liouville measure, which restricts to a measure on $A$. Clearly $F$ preserves this measure. I haven't computed the measure, but it is invariant under rotation, so is independent of $\theta$, and is invariant under reflection $(\theta,\varphi)\to (\theta,\pi-\varphi)$. One could reparameterize the $\varphi$ coordinate in terms of the Liouville measure to get an area-preserving homeomorphism of the annulus. So I would suggest you could do a literature search for results on periodic points for area-preserving homeomorphisms of an annulus.

Answer (score 5):

Following up on @Ian's comments: the magic words are "monotone twist maps of the annulus" and "Aubry-Mather theory". googling either of the above (or looking in Katok-Hasselblad, who have a whole chapter on the subject) is your best bet.